# Set string to file contents c++

Tags: c++, string, file-io

I was wanting to know if there was a simple way to set a `std::string` equal to the contents of a file in *C++*. So far, I was thinking something like this: (although I haven't tested it, so I don't know if it will work)

```
#include <fstream>
#include <string>

int main(int argc, char *argv[]){

    fstream in("file.txt");
    string str;

    str = in;

    return 0;
}
```

Is this a way to accomplish this? If not, is there a simple way to do so? Thanks!

Comment: possible duplicate of [Read whole ASCII file into C++ std::string](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2602013/read-whole-ascii-file-into-c-stdstring)

Comment: Why exactly haven't you tested it? It's the easiest way to know if it works or not :)

Comment: @Kelm: But not necessarily the most reliable way. "Appearing to work" can be very different than "actually working". Especially in a language with so much undefined, unspecified and implementation defined behavior.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is one possible solution using `vector<string>`, each element is a line.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
#include <vector>

using namespace std;

int main()
{
    // vector that will store all the file lines
    vector<string> textLines;  

    // string holding one line
    string line;  

    // attach input stream to file    
    ifstream inputFile("data.txt");

    // test stream status   
    if(!inputFile)
    {
        std::cerr << "Can't open input file!\n";
    }

    // read the text line by line
    while(getline(inputFile, line))
    {
        // store each line as vector element
        textLines.push_back(line);
    }

    // optional (stream object destroyed at end of function scope)
    inputFile.close();

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Thank you, this is working marvelously. I changed the vector to just a string, then instead of push_back, i appended line to it. Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

There is a standard way:

```
std::ifstream     file("myfilename.txt");
std::stringstream buffer;
buffer << file.rdbuf();

std::string content( buffer.str() );
```

**References**

- http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/io/basic_ostream/operator_ltlt specially item (8)

Answer (score 0):

try this one

```
#include <fstream>
#include <cstdlib>
std::string readText(const char* fileName)
{
    std::ifstream file(fileName);

    if (!file.good())
    {
        std::cout << "file fail to load..." << fileName;
        exit(1);
    }

    return std::string(std::istreambuf_iterator<char>(file),        std::istreambuf_iterator<char>());

}
```