# How do I print out the contents of a file? C++ File Stream

Tags: c++, iostream, fstream

I am using fstream and C++ and all I want my program to do is to print out to the terminal the contents of my .txt file. It may be simple, but I have looked at many things on the web and I can't find anything that will help me. How can I do this? Here is the code I have so far:

```
    #include <iostream>
#include <fstream>
using namespace std;

int main() {
    string output;
    ifstream myfile;
    ofstream myfile2;

    string STRING;
    myfile.open ("/Volumes/LFARLEIGH/Lucas.txt");

    myfile2 << "Lucas, It Worked";

        myfile >> STRING;
        cout << STRING << endl;
    myfile.close();


    return 0;
}
```

Thank you in advance. Please forgive me if this is very simple as I quite new to C++

Comment: Are you getting an error

Comment: There is an extra '}' after cout<<STRING<<endl

Comment: You open the same file twice?

Comment: Sorry about those things - not relevant. I am not getting an error the text from the file is just not coming up

Comment: Seen [this question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2602013/read-whole-ascii-file-into-c-stdstring)?

Comment: One thing to note is that the << operator will read the file until the next separator (a space by default), not the whole thing.

Answer (score 47, accepted):

There's no reason to reinvent the wheel here, when this functionality is already implemented in the standard C++ library.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <fstream>

int main()
{
    std::ifstream f("file.txt");

    if (f.is_open())
        std::cout << f.rdbuf();
}
```

Answer (score 1):

```
#include <iostream>
#include <fstream>

int main()
{
    string name ;
    std::ifstream dataFile("file.txt");
    while (!dataFile.fail() && !dataFile.eof() )
    {
          dataFile >> name ;
          cout << name << endl;
    }
```

Comment: Could you explain your code? Why is it better than the [accepted answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/35202275/711006)?

Comment: While answering, please mention what is wrong in the actual code posted and what is corrected and why it has to be corrected in that way.
Below link will help you.

https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-answer

Answer (score -1):

Try this, just modified at some places. You had tried to open a file using extracter (i.e, ifstream) but overwriting this file using inserter (i.e, ofstream) 
without opening the file, that **ifstream** and **ofstream** were two different classes. so, they don't understand.

```
#include<iostream>
#include<fstream>

using namespace std;

int main(){

    string output;
    ifstream myfile;
    ofstream myfile2;

    string STRING;
    // output stream || inserting
    myfile2.open ("/Volumes/LFARLEIGH/Lucas.txt");

    myfile2 << "Lucas, It Worked";


    myfile2.close();

    // input stream || extracting

    myfile.open("/Volumes/LFARLEIGH/Lucas.txt");

        myfile >> STRING;
        cout << STRING << endl;
    myfile.close();


   return 0;
}
```