# How do I read ALL the ASCII characters in a file in C++?

Tags: c++, file, file-io, ascii

Perhaps there is an answer to this somewhere on this site, but I can't find it for the life of me.

What I need is to get ALL the ASCII characters from a file in C++. This includes things like \n (ascii 10 in decimal), and the mysterious SUB (ascii 26 in decimal) - which seems to just act as an eof while I try to read in the file.

The issue is that I don't know of a method of reading in a file that isn't messed with when it sees things like new lines and whatnot.

I'd love to read all of these in to a vector of chars or uint8_ts.

I tried several approaches, including some found here: [Read whole ASCII file into C++ std::string](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2602013/read-whole-ascii-file-into-c-stdstring)

No luck.

Comment: What does "no luck" mean?

Comment: It means I tried the "several approaches" that I mentioned, and they didn't work.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I agree with [everything DevSolar said](https://stackoverflow.com/a/35287833/961781). I usually do something along the lines of:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <fstream>
#include <iterator>
#include <vector>

using namespace std;

int main()
{
   ifstream  f("foo.txt", ios::in | ios::binary);
   vector<char> contents(istreambuf_iterator<char>(f), (istreambuf_iterator<char>()));

   // process contents ...

}
```

Comment: One up for the iterator constructor. I had completely forgotten about that one. If you actually *do* need the whole file in a vector, that's the way to go.

Answer (score 3):

If SUB (0x1a) gave you problems, that is most likely because **you opened the file in text mode**, not binary mode, in Windows (*). Text-mode streams are allowed several implementation-defined things binary-mode streams are not, like changing the format of end-of-line (`\n` vs. `\r\n`), truncating trailing whitespace before a newline, or -- in your case -- considering 0x1a to mean end-of-file. So make sure that you use binary mode for reading binary data.

Note that binary-mode streams may have additional zero bytes at the end of the stream.

This kind of stream behaviour is specified for C99 in chapter 7.19.2 "Streams", section 2-3. I am sure similar specs are given for C11 and C++, but I cannot give you chapter and verse on those.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <fstream>
#include <sstream>

// ...

std::string filename( "foo.txt" );
std::stringstream sstr;

// It's the std::ios::binary that is making all the difference
std::ifstream in( filename.c_str(), std::ios::binary );

sstr << in.rdbuf();
```

Congratulations, you have just read the whole file into the [stringstream](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/io/basic_stringstream) `sstr`. You can get a [`string`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/string) out of that with `sstr.str()` -- and a `string` has many of the same features as a [`std::vector< char >`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/vector) -- but djf's solution for *directly* reading into a `vector<char>` is more efficient (and would *also* work for a `std::string` by the way).

---

(*): Linux makes no difference between text and binary mode.

---

All that being said, *there is no guarantee whatsoever that a file will actually contain ASCII.* Going with the assumption that you are working on Windows, the default encoding for text files is CP1252, which is quite a different thing from either ASCII or ISO 8859-1 (Latin-1) or  ISO 8859-15 (Latin-9). Welcome to the world of text encodings. My suggestion is to use [UTF-8](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/UTF-8), it's the only sane choice...

Comment: +1 for "Linux makes no difference between text and binary mode". In Windows, `0x1A` is the Ctrl+Z character, which signals end-of-file (EOF) for text mode streams.

Comment: @ubuntugod: Yea... not too long ago I was looking at some terribly convoluted code that jumped through various hoops to "encode" data so it didn't have any `0x1A` in it, and wondered, "why did the author do this?". When I eventually realized this was his "solution" for a problem he did not understand -- text vs. binary mode in Windows -- *and that I could not replace this mess with a `std::ios::binary` because the "encoding" had become part of the external ABI* -- I had to take a looong walk...

Comment: The whole `0x1A` came into the picture because of the legendary CP/M operating system. `0x1A` was used in it for marking the end of a file because, if a file had a content `Hello`, it would report that size of file in terms of **disk block** which was 128 bytes. So, `0x1A` was introduced for giving users a better way to understand the real size of the file. The EOF concept was carried over to MS-DOS as well.

Comment: @ubuntugod: The long and short of it is, basically, "if it's binary, *open* it as binary, d'uh." ;-)

Comment: Yup. Completely forgot about text/binary distinction in Windows. Thanks!