# Reading in one byte at a time with .get()

Tags: c++, file, vector, while-loop, istream

So i'm reading in a input file that contains:

```
lololololololol
```

I need to read it in using binary one byte at a time for something I'm doing later on. To do this i'm using `get()` to read it in then storing it into a char. It seems to be working correctly except for the last char that it reads in. The vector that it is reading into contains:

```
lololololololol
�
```

I'm not quite sure what this last value is but it's totally throwing off my finial output. So my question is, is there a reason `get()` would read in a value or byte from my text document that is not there? Or is it reading in something that I don't know of?

code:

```
while(istr.good()) {
    temp = istr.get();
    input.push_back(temp);
}
```

Comment: `get` returns `EOF` when the end of file is reached. `good` won't report end-of-file until that has happened. So the mysterious character is the EOF marker.

Comment: @JonathanPotter Please don't answer in comments.

Comment: Textbook example of why `while (stream is good) { read from stream; use data }` is wrong. The stream isn't made un-good until _after_ you've tried to read past the end of the buffer. `.good()` doesn't tell the future.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It's reading the `EOF` ([end of file](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/End-of-file)) character. You need to do the check **after** reading it to avoid it being inserted to the vector:

```
while(temp = istr.get(), istr.good()) // comma operator
    input.push_back(temp);
```

Or you might use the 2nd [`std::istream_base::get` overload](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/io/basic_istream/get) and let `istr` implicitly convert to `bool`:

```
while(istr.get(temp))
    input.push_back(temp);
```

Or try [more advanced approaches](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2602013/read-whole-ascii-file-into-c-stdstring). `operator>>` and `std::getline` would also work fine for this kind of input.