# When grabbing text from a binary file, why is xdg_vtnr=8 my result?

Tags: c++, command-line, binaryfiles

```
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;

int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
    cout << argv[2] << endl;
}
```

This is just the beginning of a program that I'm writing, but I'm
 already stuck. It simply reads in data from a binary file that I have
 saved in the same directory as this program. I compile and run the
 program with ./a.out < filename, and the program is just supposed to
 print out whatever is in the file to stdout. I tried a different way
 by opening the file and using getline to get the data, and the data
 was received perfectly. I'm just wanting to know why the first method
 isn't working as intended and what I can do to fix this problem.

Comment: were you expecting this program to print the filename? or the file contents?

Comment: run your program like this `.\a.out filename` and see what you get - things will be clearer

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are a few things wrong here primarily from the confusion between arguments and the input stream.

`argv` contains the arguments/parameters as an array of c-strings passed into the program when it was executed and `argc` is the number of arguments. If you were to run `./a.out filename` you should see

```
argc = 2
argv[0] = "/<current path>/a.out"
argv[1] = "filename"
```

However you run `./a.out < filename` which has no parameters and a redirection. So you accessing `argv[2]` is undefined behavior and it seems you get the junk value "xdg_vntr=8". Unfortunately I can't adequately explain why this is your result because it is undefined and would be implementation dependent on the compiler and system.

So doing `< filename` tells the shell running your program to open up `filename` and direct it into the program's standard input stream (A.K.A. `std::cin`) You can send the input stream buffer directly to the output stream like so `std::cout << std::cin.rdbuf();`

Comment: Thanks for the explanation. It really helped out. I can now get the input just by doing cin >> argv[2], but now the issue is with there being a space in the text in the file.

Comment: You can send the input stream buffer directly to the output stream like so `std::cout << std::cin.rdbuf();`. I'll update the answer

Comment: getline seems to be working for me. Thank you so much for your help!

Comment: I'll also try that. Thank you!

Comment: Okay, I don't know what I did, but it looked as though getline was working. Is there any way that I can get the contents from a file and save that to a variable using rdbuf()?

Comment: This is starting to get into another question which looks like its addressed here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2602013/read-whole-ascii-file-into-c-stdstring there are a number of solutions to reading in a file to a variable