# QGLShaderProgram OpenGL shaders

Tags: c++, qt, opengl, shader, fragment-shader

I'm getting the following error when I try link my fragment shader,

> QGLShader::compile(Fragment): 0(4) : error C0000: syntax error, unexpected '.', expecting "::" at token "."

I'm just trying to implement a simple fragment shader that sets colour to be green.

The code for my vertex shader (which is working) file name `shader.vert`

```
#version 430

in layout(location=0) vec2 position;

void main()
{
    gl_Position = vec4(position, 0.0, 1.0);
}
```

The code for my fragment shader `shader.frag`

```
#version 430

out vec4 finalColour;

void main()
{
    finalColour = vec4(0.0, 1.0, 0.0, 1.0);
}
```

The code that links the `QGLShaderProgram mProgram`

```
//Add Shaders
if (!mProgram.addShaderFromSourceFile(QGLShader::Vertex, "shader.vert")) {
    error_msg("Vertex shader load failed");
}
if (!mProgram.addShaderFromSourceCode(QGLShader::Fragment, "testShader.frag")) {
    error_msg("Fragment shader load failed");
}
if (!mProgram.link()) {
    error_msg("Cannot link shaders");
}
mProgram.bind()
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The second parameter of addShaderFromSourceCode(, code)

you must provide the content of file not the name of file itself
here you can put this code in a function and use it to load the file

[Read whole ASCII file into C++ std::string](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2602013/read-whole-ascii-file-into-c-stdstring)

Comment: For the second parameter it is asking for a filename, you can look at the specs, [QGLShaderProgram::addShaderFromSourceFile](http://doc.qt.io/qt-4.8/qglshaderprogram.html#addShaderFromSourceFile). Also shader.vert is loading fine. fragment shader is not though.

Comment: you are loading the vertex shader from file
and fragment shader from code ..
change the name of the function .. from addShaderFromSourceCode to addShaderFromSourceFile