# How do I read a binary file in C++ if I generate it in Java?

Tags: java, c++

I'm working on an encryption algorithm and I need to generate some information in Java (a binary file) to read in C++.

I'm not sure if the problem is how I create the binary file or how I read it, though I can perfectly read the information in Java.

So I made a simple test. In Java I save the number 9 to a binary file, and then I try to read it in C++, but it does not read a number.

Can someone please tell me how I can do this?

The Java code:

```
int x = 9;

        try{
            ObjectOutputStream salida=new ObjectOutputStream(new 
            FileOutputStream("test.bin"));
            salida.writeInt(x);
            salida.close();
            System.out.println("saved");
        } catch(Exception e){
            System.out.println(e);
        }
```

The C++ code:

```
streampos size;
  char * memblock;

  ifstream file ("test.bin", ios::in|ios::binary|ios::ate);
  if (file.is_open())
  {
    size = file.tellg();
    cout<< size << endl;
    memblock = new char [size];
    file.seekg (0, ios::beg);
    file.read (memblock, size);
    file.close();

    int i;
    for (i = 0; i < sizeof(memblock); i++)
    {
        cout << memblock[i] <<endl;
    }
 delete[] memblock;
  }
  else cout << "Unable to open file";
```

This is the output:

```
�
�


w
```

Comment: `cout <<` of binary data is fraught with peril. Make sure the data is null terminated, preferably at the end rather than some random point in the middle of the stream, and comprised entirely of characters that can be printed.

Comment: [Here is a whole page full of ways to read a whole file of text data into a `string`](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2602013/read-whole-ascii-file-into-c-stdstring) I like answer 2 option 1. Note how it eliminates the need to manually allocate and manage any storage.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Your problem is that you are using `ObjectOutputStream` to write the data.  This encodes the object graph in a Java-specific form intended to be read with `ObjectInputStream`.  To make the data stream compatible with C++ you would need to do one of two things:

1. Implement in C++ code that understands the output format produced by `ObjectOutputStream` -- i.e. re-implement in C++ what Java does in `ObjectInputStream`.  This is NOT recommended.
2. Write your data out from Java using a standard `FileOutputStream`, in a serialized format that *you* define, that then can be read by your C++ code.  How you specify and implement this is up to you but can be very simple, depending on the complexity of your data.

Comment: Start by deciding what byte order ([endianness](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Endianness)) you want to represent your binary data in.

Comment: I'd suggest using [`DataOutputStream`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/io/DataOutputStream.html), which will help write primitives in *big-endian* order. The class is specifically designed to write output "in a portable way".

Answer (score 1):

Yor write to file `int` (4 bytes?), in your file in hex must bu such data as `09 00 00 00`.
In your cpp code you read it to char array (you read bytes!), `file.tellg();` return 4, and you read to `char * memblock` array {9, 0, 0, 0}. And after it you print it as chars `cout << memblock[i] <<endl;`.
So you can print your out array as

```
for (i = 0; i < size / sizeof(int) / ; i++) {
   cout << ((int*)memblock)[i] <<endl;
}
```

or read it in int array

```
int* memblock;
...
memblock = new int[size / sizeof(int)];
...
file.read (memblock, (size / sizeof(int)) * sizeof(int));
```

Answer (score 1):

Java code:

```
import java.io.DataOutputStream;
import java.io.FileOutputStream;

public class Main
{

    public static void main( String[] args )
    {
        int x = 9;

        try
        {
            FileOutputStream fout = new FileOutputStream( "prueba.bin" );
            DataOutputStream salida = new DataOutputStream( fout );
            salida.writeInt( x );
            salida.close();
            System.out.println( "guardado" );
        }
        catch( Exception e )
        {
            System.out.println( e );
        }
    }
}
```

C++ Builder code:

```
unsigned char buffer[4];
ifstream file( "prueba.bin", ios::in | ios::binary );
if( file.is_open() )
{
    file.read( (char*)&buffer, sizeof( buffer ) );
    int num = buffer[ 0 ] | buffer[1] | buffer[ 2 ] | buffer[ 3 ];
    // another way to convert endianness:
    // int num = buffer[ 0 ] | ( buffer[1] << 8 ) | ( buffer[ 2 ] << 16 ) | ( buffer[ 3 ] << 24 );
}
```