# Need C++ expert to find why my content variable shows junk characters in c++ program

Tags: c++, ifstream

Need to identify why is my Variable named content showing junk characters as "ÿþE".

Below is my code :

```
std::ifstream ifs("D:\vstudio\ConsoleApplication3\DebugExport_20190617090328.txt");

std::string content(
    (std::istreambuf_iterator<char>(ifs)),
    std::istreambuf_iterator<char>()
);
```

Comment: try to use double backslash '\\' instead of '\'

Comment: The answers here have more info https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2602013/read-whole-ascii-file-into-c-stdstring

Comment: "ÿþE" googles well.  Renaming a PDF file to a .txt extension does not magically make it readable.

Comment: What are the contents of the file? What character encoding is it using? How are you outputting the string? All of that affects the result.

Answer (score -4):

some operations like cout convert string into signed char*. signed char cannot show special letters like é, î, ², ~ and many others. Then they are converted into some strange letters like these you mentioned above.

Comment: This is not an answer, kindly go through how to answer section of StackOverflow. Also this is a solvable error that the user has asked.