# potential null deference warning

Tags: c++, gcc, null

From one of the more highly voted answers here: [Read whole ASCII file into C++ std::string](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2602013/read-whole-ascii-file-into-c-stdstring)

And with a newer compiler (gcc), given this code to read a file into a string:

```cpp
std::ifstream t("file.txt");
std::string str((std::istreambuf_iterator<char>(t)),
                 std::istreambuf_iterator<char>());
```

The newer compiler gives a potential null deference warning - see: https://godbolt.org/z/KojKWT4WK

We are using the std::string constructor that takes first/last iterators - and I am happy they are set to correct values, so I don't think there is anything wrong with this code.

But the compiler is unhappy about the std library code (I guess) - perhaps that this code does not check for/handle null pointers correctly?

So the question here is, is "my" code acceptable or does it have a potential bug? - or is this a possible bug in the std lib? or is this just a false posative?

Comment: What do you think happens if the file is empty? AFAIK `std::istreambuf_iterator<char>(t)` will internally derefernce a nullptr

Comment: Code checks that `begin != end` (which **implicitly** means `begin` doesn't use `nullptr`). the analyser might not understand that relationship.

Comment: @PepijnKramer good point - I am not sure, but in my real code I do have a pre-file exists / empty check so that can be taken care of - and still  gives the warning.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> is this just a false positive?

The program is well-formed. This seems to be a false positive. Here is the submitted gcc bug:

[GCC emits warning potential null dereference](https://gcc.gnu.org/bugzilla/show_bug.cgi?id=112421)