# Overloading with CArchive operator <<

Tags: c++, serialization, mfc

I checked the link [Can I overload CArchive << operator to work with std::string?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7446484/can-i-overload-carchive-operator-to-work-with-stdstring) about overloading for string type and I used

```
CArchive& operator<<( CArchive& ar, string lhs)
{
    int size_t = lhs.size();
    ar << size_t;
    ar.Write( lhs.c_str(), size_t );
    return ar;

}

CArchive& operator>>( CArchive& ar, string lhs)
{
     int size_t = lhs.size();
     ar >> size_t;
     lhs.resize(size);
     ar.Read(&lhs[0], size);
}
```

And I declared the overloaded operators in my header function as a friend.

```
class CArrow : public CObject  
{
    DECLARE_SERIAL(CArrow)
    friend CArchive& operator<<( CArchive& ar, std::string lhs);
    friend CArchive& operator>>( CArchive& ar, std::string lhs);
  ...
  ...
}
```

But the `>>` operator gives me blank output. When I don't use as an operator, just read and write in my serialization function, they work for only one string variable. However, I have more than one string to store and load. Is there any other way to serialize the string type? or What is the problem with this overloaded functions?

Comment: Your >> operator needs to specify a reference to a string!

And your << operator needs to specify a const reference.

Comment: It worked. Please write it down this and I will accept as an answer. But I didn't understand why, Could you explain it for me, please?

Answer (score 0):

Your operator >> seems to be writing the size to ar instead of reading it from ar.

You should add the MFC tag to your question.

Comment: I corrected operator typo in my question and added MFC tag. Thanks. But the problem wasn't that.