# Is it possible to add `<<` and `>>` operators to a structure itself for serialization to CArchive?

Tags: visual-c++, structure, operator-keyword, carchive

I have this structure:

```
using BETHEL_SPEAKER_SERVICE_TALK_INFO_S = struct tagBethelSpeakerServiceTalkInfo
{
    CString strHost;
    CString strCohost;
    CString strChairman;
    CString strOpenPrayer;
    CString strSpeaker;
    CString strTheme;
    int iSongOpen{};
    int iSongClose{};
};
```

It is a member variable in a class:

```
BETHEL_SPEAKER_SERVICE_TALK_INFO_S GetBethelServiceTalkInfo() const { return m_BSSTI; }
```

I want to serialize this structure to my `CArchive`. At the moment I have for storing:

```
ar << m_bSpecialEventBethelServiceTalk;
ar << m_BSSTI.strHost;
ar << m_BSSTI.strCohost;
ar << m_BSSTI.strChairman;
ar << m_BSSTI.strOpenPrayer;
ar << m_BSSTI.strSpeaker;
ar << m_BSSTI.strTheme;
ar << gsl::narrow<WORD>(m_BSSTI.iSongOpen);
ar << gsl::narrow<WORD>(m_BSSTI.iSongClose);
```

Similar for reading:

```
ar >> m_bSpecialEventBethelServiceTalk;
ar >> m_BSSTI.strHost;
ar >> m_BSSTI.strCohost;
ar >> m_BSSTI.strChairman;
ar >> m_BSSTI.strOpenPrayer;
ar >> m_BSSTI.strSpeaker;
ar >> m_BSSTI.strTheme;
m_BSSTI.iSongOpen = readAndCast<int, WORD>(ar);
m_BSSTI.iSongClose = readAndCast<int, WORD>(ar);
```

Is it possible to add `<<` and `>>` operators to the structure itself?

---

I am new to trying out the `operator<<` referred to in the linked answer but I am having issues. For example, I tried:

```
friend CArchive operator<<(CArchive& rArchive, BETHEL_SPEAKER_SERVICE_TALK_INFO_S const& rsBSSTI)
{
    return  rArchive << rsBSSTI.strHost
                     << rsBSSTI.strCohost
                     << rsBSSTI.strChairman
                     << rsBSSTI.strOpenPrayer
                     << rsBSSTI.strSpeaker
                     << rsBSSTI.strTheme
                     << gsl::narrow<WORD>(rsBSSTI.iSongOpen)
                     << gsl::narrow<WORD>(rsBSSTI.iSongClose);
```

And in the other part of my code:

```
ar << m_BSSTI;
```

But when I compile:

> ```
> 7>D:\My Programs\2022\MeetSchedAssist\Meeting Schedule Assistant\SpecialEventManager.h(44,49): error C2061: syntax error:
> ```
>
> identifier 'BETHEL_SPEAKER_SERVICE_TALK_INFO_S'
> 7>D:\My Programs\2022\MeetSchedAssist\Meeting Schedule Assistant\SpecialEventManager.h(45,2): error C2805: binary 'operator
> <<' has too few parameters
> 7>D:\My Programs\2022\MeetSchedAssist\Meeting Schedule Assistant\SpecialEventManager.h(46,3): error C2059: syntax error:
> 'return'
> 7>D:\My Programs\2022\MeetSchedAssist\Meeting Schedule Assistant\SpecialEventManager.h(53,48): error C2238: unexpected
> token(s) preceding ';'
> 7>D:\My Programs\2022\MeetSchedAssist\Meeting Schedule Assistant\SpecialEventManager.h(55,1): error C2143: syntax error:
> missing ';' before '}'
> 7>D:\My Programs\2022\MeetSchedAssist\Meeting Schedule Assistant\SpecialEventManager.h(55,1): error C2059: syntax error: '}'
> 7>AssignSelectedColumnDlg.cpp

---

Here is the full thing so far:

```
using BETHEL_SPEAKER_SERVICE_TALK_INFO_S = struct tagBethelSpeakerServiceTalkInfo
{
    CString strHost;
    CString strCohost;
    CString strChairman;
    CString strOpenPrayer;
    CString strSpeaker;
    CString strTheme;
    int iSongOpen{};
    int iSongClose{};

    friend CArchive& operator<<(CArchive& rArchive, BETHEL_SPEAKER_SERVICE_TALK_INFO_S const& rsBSSTI)
    {
        return  rArchive << rsBSSTI.strHost << rsBSSTI.strCohost
                         << rsBSSTI.strChairman
                         << rsBSSTI.strOpenPrayer
                         << rsBSSTI.strSpeaker
                         << rsBSSTI.strTheme
                         << gsl::narrow<WORD>(rsBSSTI.iSongOpen)
                         << gsl::narrow<WORD>(rsBSSTI.iSongClose);
    }
};
```

With the above the first error is on line #44 which is:

```
friend CArchive& operator<<(CArchive& rArchive, BETHEL_SPEAKER_SERVICE_TALK_INFO_S const& rsBSSTI)
```

Comment: @RaymondChen Let me try and digest the liked answer before I accept it as the resolution. But it sounds promising.

Comment: @RaymondChen I am having problems trying to implement the linked answer.

Comment: There's not enough information in your question to be of much assistance. Which line is line 45? Where did you put the `friend` declaration relative to the structure definition? What is "the other part of my code"?

Comment: @RaymondChen See updated question.

Comment: Notice that the error message is "syntax error: dentifier 'BETHEL_SPEAKER_SERVICE_TALK_INFO_S'". You are using `BETHEL_SPEAKER_SERVICE_TALK_INFO_S` inside the definition of `tagBethelSpeakerServiceTalkInfo` before `BETHEL_SPEAKER_SERVICE_TALK_INFO_S` has been defined. (It doesn't become defined until after the `using` statement is complete.) Has nothing to do with overloading. Inside the `tagBethelSpeakerServiceTalkInfo` definition, you have to call the class `tagBethelSpeakerServiceTalkInfo`. The alias name is not available until later. (But why create an alias anyway?)

Comment: @RaymondChen That was it. Historically I just used the tags. Partly because I preferred the ClassView showing my list of tag names which makes much more sense.

Comment: This question also helped: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22646705/overloading-with-carchive-operator