# How to put char array into std::string

Tags: c++, string, std

I allocate a char array  then I need to return it as a string, but I don't want to copy this char array and then release its memory.

```
        char* value = new char[required];
        f(name, required, value, NULL); // fill the array
        strResult->assign(value, required);
        delete [] value;
```

I don't want to do like above. I need put the array right in the std string container. How I can do that?

**Edit1:**

I understood that I should not and that the string is not designed for this purpose. MB somebody know another container implementation for char array with which I can do that?

Comment: "*MB somebody know another container implementation for char array with which I can do that?*" `std::vector<char>`...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You shouldn't. `std::strings` were not designed to expose their internal data to be used as a buffer.
It's not guaranteed that the string's buffer address won't change during execution of an external function, especially not if the function allocates or deallocates memory itself.
And it's not guaranteed that the string's buffer is contiguous.

See, for example, [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1042940/writing-directly-to-stdstring-internal-buffers).

The example in your post is the better way to do it.

Answer (score 6):

In C++11, the following is guaranteed to work:

```
std::string strResult(required, '\0');
f(name, required, &strResult[0], NULL);

// optionally, to remove the extraneous trailing NUL (assuming f NUL-terminates):
strResult.pop_back();

return strResult;
```

In C++03 that's not *guaranteed* to work, but it is addressed by [Library Issue 530](http://www.open-std.org/jtc1/sc22/wg21/docs/lwg-defects.html#530) which most standard library implementations have had implemented for years, so it's *probably* safe, but ultimately is implementation-dependent.

Comment: It does not work I got a fatal error from my application when I did that.

Comment: @itun : Then you're obviously using one of those non-C++11 implementations I referred to. ;-]

Comment: I know I use the last MinGW without C++11 support flag.

Answer (score 3):

Instead of passing `value` into the function, pass in `&s[0]`, where `s` is a `std::string` of the right length.

Comment: You mean `value` instead of `required`. But it won't work. the std::string's buffer is read-only.

Comment: +1 but I guess you mean instead of passing _value_ into the function.

Comment: @MrLister A string is not read only, unless it is declared as const. The conversion from &s[0] to char* is fine.

Comment: Hm, I'll have to do some serious testing and internet searching.

Comment: Yes, I meant `value`, wasn't concentrating sorry.

Comment: @rasmus : `&s[0]` _is_ a `char*`, there's no conversion.

Comment: I did some searching and I found that it's _possible_, but _not recommended_ to pass the address of the string's buffer to a function. See my edited answer.

Answer (score 0):

You're gonna have to copy it to a string. AFAIK std::string does not let you access it's internals directory to do any sort of an address based direct assignment.

```
std::string s(charArry);
```